# Modify all array entries in all records of a table at once

Tags: postgresql, update, array

I have a schema that involves an array of timestamps. Due to an import problem all the timestamps are off by one hour (time zone issue). I'd like to update all the timestamps in all the records with one UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can update all the array entries like this:

```
UPDATE ambient_properties ap
SET recording_time = 
    (
        SELECT ARRAY(
            SELECT unnest(ap.recording_time) - interval '1 hours' 
        )
    );
```

The same strategy should also work for values of other types.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ce8d0/12)

Comment: You need a co-related sub-query for this. You query aggregates **all** rows into each column. Or remove the `FROM ambient_properties ap` completely as it is not needed

Comment: Damn, you're right... How do I achieve this then? Do I have to use a function?

Comment: Just remove `FROM ambient_properties ap` from you query and it works as you thought it would

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you so much. That's beautiful!